# 'mutex': is not a member of 'std' error in msvc

Tags: c++, struct, header, mutex

The following code which resides in one of my header files produces the error. There was no problem when the mutex was in a source file and I was using it with extern as a global variable. Thank you!

```
#include <memory>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::mutex m;
};
```

Comment: You need to include `<mutex>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want include the file where [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is located at, in `<mutex>`

```
#include <mutex>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::mutex m;
}
```

Comment: The advice about multiple mutexes is very bad, and can cause major performance problems. A single mutex would lock **every** instance of `MyStruct` even when you would only need to lock a single instance. And the link has multiple answers showing of the C++ mechanisms to handle multiple mutexes - those mechanisms were designed intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the mutex header?
If not, that's why compiler correctly complains: it cant find the mutex declaration...

Read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex
and then add this include

```
#include <mutex>
```